# Recommendations for a bottle supplier

Tags: bottles

I've been struggling to find a supplier in the UK who sells amber 330ml bottles suitable for European crown caps. I'm looking for glass or plastic bottles preferably of the tall style as opposed to the dumpy Belgian style.

Answer (score 2):

Go to a brewery that uses the bottles you want and ask them where they buy from. If their seller is not willing to sell to you, ask the brewery if you can buy from/through them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for bottles suppliers in the UK it can be worth checking out the [SIBA directory](http://www.siba.co.uk/directory/supplier-associate-members/bottle-glass-can-manufacturers/). Some of these will be able to supply home brew quantities, and if not they may be able to point you towards resellers who can supply sub-pallet quantities.